# How to set a "blank" initial sort order for ng-grid

Tags: sorting, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an angularjs application that uses an ng-grid. I need to be able to persist the sort order state of the grid even when the grid is repopulated.

The app uses a service that manages state, including the grid configuration, and this provides the persistence that I need:

```
//variable defined in service, and exposed via controller to grid
var gridConfig = {
    data: 'withCandidate',
    multiSelect: false,
    selectedItems: [],
    columnDefs: getAlternateColumnDefinition(),
    rowTemplate: 'Templates/grids/WithCandidateCaseRow.html',
    headerRowHeight: 20,
    rowHeight: 20,
    sortInfo: { fields: ["CaseNumber"], directions: [] }
};

<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridConfig"></div>
```

The sort order is persisted by the `sortInfo` object supplied. This works fine. However, ideally I would like the grid to have *no* initial sort order, but still persist any selection made by the user. That means using an empty `sortInfo` object, but I can't find out how to configure it. I have tried the following, but all produce angular script errors.

```
sortInfo: null
sortInfo: { }
sortInfo: { fields: [], directions: [] }
sortInfo: { fields: [""], directions: [] }
sortInfo: { fields: [null], directions: [] }
```

Is this possible? How can I define a `null sortInfo` object?

Comment: You should be able to just leave out sortInfo but I'm not not sure if your service will still be able to manage that

Comment: If you leave out the sortInfo, it doesn't persist the grid sort state when it is repopulated ... that's why I need to set that property on the config object.

Comment: Try this: sortInfo: { fields: [''], directions: [''] }

Comment: No luck. The directions array in fact can be empty, but not the fields array.

Comment: that's weird, worked for me in a plunker when I was just using gridOptions: see http://plnkr.co/edit/0ReaXy

Comment: did you check for js errors though? And did sorting actually work when the grid's loaded? I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at Object.angular.module.factory.sortService.getSortFn (http://localhost/MyApp/Scripts/framework/ng-grid-2.0.7.js:506:43)`

Comment: OK, I used sortInfo: { fields: [''], directions: [] } not sortInfo: { fields: [''], directions: [''] }.. Plunker is fixed now